# Child table detail should work like independent table when parent is also a display table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here is my table I have made my table using display table.
My problem is when I am rendering this HTML child table takes place in the first cell of the parent table and it looks weird. What CSS I should use to prevent?

```
    <div style="display:table;width:100%">
        <div style="display:table-row">
            <span style="display:table-cell">state</span>
            <span style="display:table-cell">Country</span>
            <span style="display:table-cell">Pin Code</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-row">
            <span style="display:table-cell;">JH</span>
            <span style="display:table-cell;">Jfjkfjf</span>
            <span style="display:table-cell;">831001</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table;width:100%;">
            <div style="display:table-row">
                <span style="display:table-cell">Contact ID</span>
                <span style="display:table-cell">Contact Name</span>
            </div>
            <div style="display:table-row">
                <span style="display:table-cell;">1</span>
                <span style="display:table-cell;">jkjkjgkjgkjgk</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-row">
            <span style="display:table-cell;">JH</span>
            <span style="display:table-cell;">Jfjkfjf</span>
            <span style="display:table-cell;">831001</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have to put the child table in a table cell.

Comment: @Huelfe now it is talking 2nd cell of the parent table

Comment: my question is child table should not affect the parent table.

Comment: You are trying to put the child table inbetween two rows of the parent table, but that is not how tables are supposed to work. You should put the child table inside one cell of the outer table.